# Argument 1:Cannot convert from NetSatis.Entities.interfaces.ientity to fluentvalidation.ivalidationcontext

Tags: c#, .net

```
public static class ValidatorTool
{
    public static bool Validate(IValidator validator,IEntity entity)
    {
        bool result = true;
        var validationResult = validator.Validate(entity);
        if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            string message = null;
            foreach (var error in validationResult.Errors)
            {
                message += error.ErrorMessage+System.Environment.NewLine;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(message);
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
```

I am trying to use validator tools but one day ago i dont get any errors about this entity thing but now i am taking an error about entity, What should i do in order to not get an error

Answer (score 0):

This is a change on [FluentValidation 9](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/upgrading-to-9.html#removal-of-non-generic-validate-overload), the code below will work:

```
var context = new ValidationContext<IEntity>(request);
var validationResult = validator.Validate(context);
```